# nginx proxy_pass with https protocol leads to "invalid URL prefix" error

Tags: heroku, nginx, dokku, x-accel-redirect

I'm running a php app behind nginx on dokku. I got a location with a proxy_pass directive defined like this:

```
location ~* ^/cdn/(.*?)/(.*) {
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  proxy_set_header HOST $1;
  proxy_pass https://$1/$2?$args;
}
```

I'd like to use this location to redirect files from S3.

In the error logs I have the following error:

```
2016/10/03 21:56:46 [error] 251#0: *11 invalid URL prefix 
  in "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg?", 
  client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, 
  request: "GET /cdn/s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg HTTP/1.1"
```

Everything works well if I change **https://** and use **http://** instead.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I build the app with the heroku php buildpack (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php)

Answer (score 0):

It will work, if you remove variables from the host part of your `proxy_pass`. I hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

check your nginx config ,make sure your have ngx_http_ssl_module

```
cd /usr/sbin/
./nginx -V
```

should show

> TLS SNI support enabled